# Table access by which user in big query

Tags: logging, google-bigquery

Wanted to know which user executed select statement on specific dataset in last 6 month in big query or any DML executed.
wanted to know which user having permission to which table.
user name along with table name and time when select or any DML executed.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud writes audit logs containing detailed information about operational actions such as executing queries, amongst others. You can find more detailed information on how BigQuery handles audit logs and guides that will help you gather this information, such as Log-based alerts, on the following [public article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/introduction-audit-workloads).

This way, you will know which principal executed a query against your datasets, and as audit logs retention period is up to [400 days](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods), you’ll query up to 6 months guaranteed.

Moreover, as you mentioned that you would like to know which user has permission at table level, you can grant roles through IAM that will let principals modify their tables, and these roles, which can be [predefined ones](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery) or custom, can be applied at [dataset, table or view level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions-predefined-roles). This means that you could extract this information by consulting the list of permissions on each resource or, alteratively, filter by roles on the IAM page.

Hope this information could help you. Have a great weekend!